# Downloading Visual Studio Pro 2013 without MSDN

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I want to download a free trial of visual studio pro 2013 but in their site i found a version but with MSDN included it's size is about 2.7 GB, it will take long time for me to download it (because i have a modest speed connection), i want to know if there is a version of visual studio pro 2013 (not express) without MSDN which has less size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the "Install Now" link on the Visual Studio page, it will download a small bootstrap installer file and then let you select what parts of Visual Studio Professional that you want to use.  The 2.7GB is the entire set of all technologies (C#, VB.NET, C++, SharePoint etc etc).

[VS 2013 Pro Install Now](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs)

This way you will be able to make your install tailored to your specific use and reduce the overall download size.

You will however, have to use the same installer to ever change your installation.  If you have the full ISO, then you will not have to go back online again to make any changes.

Comment: This link does not work anymore because the #$%^& from MS removed it with VS2017. I have a real DVD here, and a License-Key but no DVD-Drive in my computer. Nadellas Microsoft became such an unreliable crap! Cost me half a workday by now...